# Static backdrop on Bootstrap 4 is not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm implementing Bootstrap 4 Modal. The modal is manually shown (not via button).

On its document, it is either:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

or:

```
$('#myModal').modal({keyboard: true, backdrop: "static", show: false});
```

There is no combinaation of both which happens I needed it badly.

This is my code:

```
let myModal = $('#myModal');

myModal.modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show: false,
}).on("show.bs.modal", function(event) {
    $(this).find('.modal-title').html('Success');
    $(this).find('.modal-body').html('${message}');
    let closeModal = $('<button id="close-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>');
    $(this).find('.modal-footer').append(closeModal);
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
    $(this).find('.modal-title').html('');
    $(this).find('.modal-body').html('');
    $(this).find('.modal-footer').html('');
});

myModal.modal('show');
```

How do I show the modal with options (keyboard, backdrop and show)?

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: There is none. There is modal-backdrop added to class along with modal and fade on the root div of modal. There is nothing I can do on the page. I can't esc, click button, etc.

Comment: It works well if I have button that opens the modal and if i a remove(myModal.modal('show');).

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I wondering why it's working on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6yqpwoaL/

Comment: then something wrong with your html code. try with your exact html code.